# Can you just store binaries?

Tags: artifactory, binaries

We are using Artifactory Enterprise and, in addition to "normal" usage, we would like to just store some binaries in Artifactory. This is so we can limit egress and pull the binaries from Artifactory instead of the general Internet. Is this possible? Is there a documentation link that will help explain the process?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done by creating a [generic local repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-GenericRepositories) and deploy the binaries thru UI or using the REST API and you can use the binaries from generic local repository. Refer to this [blog](https://jfrog.com/blog/5-special-repositories-in-artifactory-you-should-know-about/) as well.